# Hive partitions by date?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I have one external table like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TAB(ID INT, NAME STRING) PARTITIONED BY(YEAR INT, MONTH STRING , DATES INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

I have data like

```
/user/input/2015/jan/1;
/user/input/2015/jan/30
```

like that years 2000 to 2016 ,every year with 12 months and 30 days;

```
ALTER TABLE TAB ADD PARTITION(year = '2015', month = 'jan',dates = '5') LOCATION '/user/input/2015/jan/1';
```

if i do like this i am getting only one day data ;

```
select * from TAB where (year = '2015', month = 'jan',dates = '5');
```

if  I run

```
select * from TAB where (year = '2015', month = 'jan',dates = '6');
```

I am not getting any data. Please help me on this how to alter table for the above scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table tab(id int,name string,dt string) partitioned by (year string,month string);

create table samp(id int,name string,dt string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';

load data inpath '\dir' into table samp;
insert overwrite table tab partition (y,m) select id,name dt,YEAR(dt),MONTH(dt) from samp;
```

Comment: In this case i don't want to load data to local.Is there any alternative ??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 1 day for `ALTER TABLE TAB ADD PARTITION(year = '2015', month = 'jan',dates = '5') LOCATION '/user/input/2015/jan/1';` because you are specifying 1 file in your location value

For 5 days create the partition as below

```
ALTER TABLE TAB 
ADD PARTITION(dates <= '5') 
LOCATION '/user/input/2015/jan/';
```

Comment: mismatched input '<=' expecting ) near 'dates' in add partition statement; line 2 pos 20

Answer (score 0):

alter table with all dates only option, I am following the same like
"ALTER TABLE TAB ADD PARTITION(year = '2015', month = 'jan',dates = '5') LOCATION '/user/input/2015/jan/1'; "